# In Pytest, how can I check if a method was called from another method?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest

I'm using Python 3.8 and pytest 6.0.1.  I have this class

```
class MyHelperService:
    def __init__(self, args):
        ...

    def my_method1(self):
        ... logic here ...
```

Then in another class, I invoke the method from the above ..

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        ...
                sb = MyHelperService(args)
                sb.my_method1()
```

How, in pytest, do I mock "my_method1" so that I can test that it was called without necessarily executing all the logic within it?

```
def test_run_it():
    ...
    resp = _import.main(req)
```

Comment: Use `@mock.patch("your_module.MyHelperService.my_method1")` on your test. Check the documentation of [mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch). You can then use the `assert_run_...` methods on the mock.

Comment: Does this work with pytest?

Comment: Yes, it does. There also the `pytest-mock` plugin, that provides the `mocker` fixture (which wraps the `unittest.mock.patch`), though you don't need it. There's a lot of question on SO about this (have answered a few myself), so there should be a lot of examples.

Comment: I'm not finding examples that pertain to my situation.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I added a generic answer, please check if that matches your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `MyHelperService` lives in `my_project/my_helper_service.py`, and `main` in `my_project/main.py`, *and* assuming that in `main` you import the class like:

```py
from my_project.my_helper_service import MyHelperService
```

you can patch your method like this (I assume that you use another fixture `my_fixture` as per the comments):

```py
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch("my_project.main.MyHelperService.my_method1")
def test_run_it(method1_mock, my_fixture):
    ...
    resp = _import.main(req)
    method1_mock.assert_called_once()
```

This replaces `method1` by a mock that just records all calls without executing the original code. Note that the mock arguments are positional arguments and therefore most be the first arguments, while fixture arguments are keyword arguments (that must be located after the positional arguments).

Alternatively, you can use the context manager version:

```py
def test_run_it(my_fixture):
    ...
    with mock.patch("my_project.main.MyHelperService.my_method1") as method1_mock:
        resp = _import.main(req)
        method1_mock.assert_called_once()
```

or the `mocker` version, if you have installed `pytest-mock`:

```py
def test_run_it(mocker, my_fixture):
    ...
    method1_mock = mocker.patch("my_project.main.MyHelperService.my_method1")
    resp = _import.main(req)
    method1_mock.assert_called_once()
```

*Some helpful links:*

- the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)
- this [blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201908/why_your_mock_doesnt_work.html) by Ned Batchelder
- this [cheat sheet](https://medium.com/@yeraydiazdiaz/what-the-mock-cheatsheet-mocking-in-python-6a71db997832) for mocking in Python

Comment: The second solution worked for me real well.  I'm passing a fixture into my test and I think the first solution caused the mock to be applied to the fixture, but got it working, which is the main thing.  Will come back and award bounty tomorrow when SO lets me.

Comment: Maybe you got the order wrong - I added a fixture to the examples in the answer to clarify this.