# Mocking subprocess of a python script

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, subprocess

I have a simple python script `so.py` that runs a subprocess command:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def commandRunner(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    if (err):
        print("there was an error", err)
        exit()
    return out

def main():
    command = "ls -la"
    res = commandRunner(command.split())
    print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and in my test file `test_so.py` ([adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692440/mocking-a-subprocess-call-in-python)):

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from so import *
from unittest import mock

class SOTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('so.subprocess.Popen')
    def test_commandRunner(self,mock_cmd):
        process_mock = mock.Mock()
        attrs = {'communicate.return_value': ('out', '')}
        process_mock.configure_mock(**attrs)
        mock_cmd.return_value = process_mock
        command = 'test this out'
        self.assertEqual(commandRunner(command.split()),'out')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'so.subprocess'; 'so' is not a package`.

If I instead use `@patch('subprocess.Popen')` it actually tries to run the command:
`AssertionError: b'total 164\n-r-xr-xr-x  23 darwin  wiff[972 chars]py\n' != 'out'`.

How do I unit test this script? All the other answers seem to have python packages instead.

Comment: As you do `from subprocess import  Popen`, you have to patch this reference, e.g. `@patch('so.Popen')`, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: This was it, why is this the case? anything I can read about? (If you like, make it an answer and ill select it)

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked in the comment? There are also existing issues where this is explained -  for example I answered a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62625882/12480730), or check the links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690318/12480730).